# Maven simple archetype for ejb (without web app and servlets)

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am looking for a simple archetype for EJB with working example.
I want build a single EAR file with pure EJBs (Servlet and WebApp are not required)

I have used this `maven-archetype-j2ee-simple` archetype and deleted `servlets` and `projects` `primary-source` and `src` folders.

I am able to build, but I am not able to deploy in to GlassFish, when I run the command `mvn glassfish:deploy` it is always looking for `.war` file inside the `target` folder.

Comment: Can you share with us your new project structure?

Comment: How the servlets and projects were removed exactly? Did they still referenced as ear modules?
Please share your pom.xml file along with exception trace.

Comment: In Maven pom file, why not just specify <exclude> with the ones you don't want.